# Traduction du « literally » argotique ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, registre-familier, langage-informel

Bon, en anglais on dit SUPER souvent « literally » pour souligner quelque chose. Par exemple :

*« I literally can’t stand you. »*

*« Literally stop! »*

*« Did you literally eat six burgers? »*

*« Are you literally kidding me... »*

On dit que c’est embêtant ce mot mais enfin moi je le dis tout le temps.

Qu’est-ce qu’on dirait en français dans ces cas ?

Comment: Literally n'est pas du tout argotique en anglais. To say something literally or ask someone about doing something, literally, etc. or for emphasis: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/literally

Comment: yeah i suppose you’re right. i am a native english speaker but it’s more just a different and maybe informal use of the word than a slang use

Comment: Related: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/25797/litt%c3%a9ralement-non-litt%c3%a9ralement

Answer (score 3):

To convey a ***metaphorical*** idea, you san say, for instance:

> On a été **littéralement scotchés** par la voix angélique de cette jeune diva.

... in the sense of:

> On a été **totalement bluffés** par ...

- While you do hear "*littéralement*" used like this in conversation, it is *academically* frowned upon.
- On the other hand, when "*literally*" is used slangily to convey a blown-out-of-proportion emphasis in ***non-metaphorical*** contexts like the ones in your examples, personally I'd rather use other emphatic adverbs than "*littéralement*" -- arguably, an anglicism, a calque.

Rather than:

> Je ne peux **littéralement** pas supporter ...
>
> C'était **littéralement** magnifique.

I'd prefer:

> **Franchement**, je ne peux pas supporter ...
>
> C'était **carrément** magnifique.

etc.

Comment: “To convey a metaphorical idea, you can say”, that's very exactly what you shouldn't do according to the literal meaning of “literally”, both in English and French. You'd say “littéralement scotché” to make a joke when you have tape on your face for example. I know the OP is after a non-literal use of *literally*. But you're just adding more confusion with this answer. As far as I know there is about no difference regarding “literally” vs “littéralement”. Both have the same literal *and* informal, controversial uses (not sure about the frequencies of each though).

Comment: https://theoatmeal.com/comics/literally

Answer (score 3):

Je suis d'accord avec la réponse donnée par @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens pour dire qu'en français « littéralement » est peu employé en dehors de son sens littéral. Le mot est employé comme synonyme de « absolument<sup>1</sup> », ce qui reste proche de son sens littéral. Mais, et même si on l'entend effectivement parfois en français, l'emploi comme synonyme de « simplement », qui est courant en anglais<sup>2</sup>, sonne à mes oreilles comme un anglicisme.

Aux propositions de @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens je rajouterai *simplement* (souvent renforcé par **tout**) et *tout bonnement* (jamais sans **tout**).

> Je ne te supporte **tout simplement** pas.

et, un peu plus familier :

> Je ne te supporte **tout bonnement** pas.

Et *vraiment*/*réellement* :

> Tu as **vraiment** mangé six burgers?
>   Tu me fais **réellement** marcher ..?

---

<sup>1</sup> Voir le TLF, B [sens par extension](https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/litt%C3%A9ralement).
<sup>2</sup> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/fr/dictionnaire/anglais/literally

Answer (score 0):

La [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?T1=litt%C3%A9ralement&id=4484) dit que dans le sens de « très, tout à fait », l'emploi de *littéralement* relèverait de la langue familière et on suggère plutôt dans un registre soutenu, selon le contexte, « absolument, complètement, entièrement, réellement, tout à fait, totalement, etc. » ; [Ac.9](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/litt%C3%A9ralement) donne comme sens « véritablement, à proprement parler ».

Answer (score 0):

Il ne me semble pas que tous les emplois relèvent du soi-disant registre « argotique ».

**I**  I literally can’t stand you.
  Literally stop!

L'emploi dans la première et la seconde phrase ne serait pas couvert par les définitions habituelles, selon l'impression que j'en ai, et donc seraient du type décrit (« argotique »).

Il semble que "literally" soit utilisé avec l'intention de dissiper tout doute et donc les traductions suivantes pourraient correspondre, bien qu'elles appartiennent à un registre de langue normal.

- Je ne ris pas, je ne peux pas vous voir.
- Sachez-le, je ne peux pas te/vous voir.

- Je ne ris pas , arrête!
- Sérieusement, arrête!

**II**  Did you literally eat six burgers?

Il me semble que le cas de la troisième phrase se rattache à une définition habituelle ;

> used to emphasise the truth of something that may seem surprising
>   *Are there literally hundreds of prizes to be won ?*

Donc, la traduction suivante est sans problème ;

- Tu as vraiement/réellement mangé six hamburgers ?

**III**  Are you literally kidding me...

La quatrième phrase me laisse sans moyens. Ce ne peut pas être « Are you really kidding me? » (It can't be true, it's a joke, right?) ; je ne vois pas une autre possibilité et apparemment il faut qu'il y en ait une autre.

Comment: literally n'est pas ni n'a jamais été un mot argotique.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne crois pas que ce soit ce que je dis ; je me réfère au texte de la question qui nous apprend que **l'usage** considéré est argotique; il aurait peut être fallu que je préserve les guillemets.

Comment: @Lambie vous avez raison, ce n’est pas trop argotique mais c’est bien informel cet usage et cet usage est courant chez les ados bien sûr